# Connect to MSSQL using DBI

Tags: r, r-dbi

I can not connect to MSSQL using DBI package. 
I am trying the way shown in package itself

```
    m <- dbDriver("RODBC") # error
```

Error: could not find function "RODBC"

```
    # open the connection using user, passsword, etc., as
    # specified in the file \file{\$HOME/.my.cnf}
    con <- dbConnect(m, dsn="data.source", uid="user", pwd="password"))
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there used to be a RODBC driver for DBI, but not any more:

http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DBI.RODBC/

A bit of tweaking has got this to install in a version 3 R but I don't have any ODBC sources to test it on. But `m = dbDriver("RODBC")` doesn't error.

```
> m = dbDriver("RODBC")
> m
<ODBCDriver:(29781)> 
>
```

Suggest you ask on the R-sig-db mailing list to maybe find out what happened to this code and/or the author...

Answer (score 15):

As an update to this question: RStudio have since created the [odbc package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/index.html) (or [GitHub version here](https://github.com/rstats-db/odbc)) that handles ODBC connections to a number of databases through DBI. For SQL Server you use:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      driver = "SQL Server",
                      server = <serverURL>,
                      database = <databasename>,
                      uid = <username>,
                      pwd = <passwd>)
```

You can also set a dsn or supply a connection string.

Comment: And the major advantage of `odbc` compared to `RODBC` is the improved insert performance using e. g. `dbWriteTable`, see [Feature request: Support for ODBC bulk insert and update operations](https://github.com/rstats-db/odbc/issues/34)

Comment: (read the `odbc` GitHub readme file)... In addition to installing the R package, you need to install an ODBC driver on your machine. If you install the ODBC SQL Server driver from Microsoft, then set `driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"` instead. Look at what drivers are available via `odbcinst -j` find the DRIVERS line location and view that file, e.g., `more /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini`

Answer (score -1):

Solved.
I used library RODBC. It has great functionality to connect sql and run sql queries in R.

## Loading Library:

```
library(RODBC)
```

# dbDriver is connection string with userID, database name, password etc.

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(dbDriver)
```

## Running Sql query

```
sqlQuery(channel=dbhandle, query)
```

Thats It.