# How to use DSN file for connection to SQL Server using R

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc, dsn

I want to use a DSN file to connect to a SQL Server database with the R library RODBC. I am able to create a User DSN and connect using the uid and pwd, but I want to exclude those from the script if possible. I have my dsn in the working directly for R which is validated by using getwd().

The examples I see show this command:

```
odbcConnect(dsn = "<dsn_file>").
```

I have tried using the DBI and RODBC packages using dbconnect and odbcConnect.

```
dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
"user_dsn",uid="username",pwd="password",database="db_name")
```

I would like to connect to the database without showing the uid and pwd in the script. I want to use a dsn file, So I can change the credentials in one place rather than in many scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to a system set up to test it but I would check this link on how to connect [Setting up R to connect to SQL Server](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/214510788-Setting-up-R-to-connect-to-SQL-Server-)
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866011/connect-to-mssql-using-dbi) one on SO for info about the RODBC library.

> Using a DSN
>   con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "mydbalias")

here are information about [Securing Credentials](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/managing-credentials/)

Comment: I tried using the dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "alias") with no luck. If I have to use another route such as keyring I can but I just see a lot of examples showing just the dsn alias for connection.

Comment: I don't have the environment to test it but have you tried using the DBI library instead of RODBC?  There are many links in the pages provided that should help with setting things up, [this link](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/microsoft-sql-server/)  is specific to MSSQL Server. [This link](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc) has info about DBI on Github.

Comment: Yeah I have tried using the DBI library as well. I am going to try the keyring method since I can't get the DSN to work.

Comment: Keyring works but will require two locations of management as I would like to use the DSN to store hostname/driver and the keyring will be used for the uid/pwd.

Answer (score 1):

I have a DSN called "phone" that connects to our phone database. To connect and then query that database, I just do the following:

```
library(RODBC)
phone <- odbcConnect("phone")
```

Answer (score 0):

With `odbc` package I use `filedsn` parametr ([described on microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldriverconnect-function?view=sql-server-ver16)). I think it should work with `RODBC`.

```
db_conn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), filedsn="path/to/my/file/user_dsn.dsn")
```